# how to set multiple text views with radio button in list view single choice mode in android using simple adapter

Tags: android

I have problem in list view with single choice mode. I want to display three text views with one radio button in list view. list view working properly. The problem is single choice mode. i want to select only one list item at a time rest of thing unselect mode. I searched last three days still i won't get any idea. Could you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a variable that saves the radiobutton chosen.

In each radiobuttons onclick you could set the variable value and set the rest of the radiobuttons to unchecked.

Hints:

in the radiobutton xml add: android:onClick"method name"

In the method add View view as an argument (example: public void clickMethod(View view).....)

Comment: Thanks for reply RomanK.I tried that one not working me.Could please give some samples

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you can display 3 textviews and a radioButton without customize ArrayAdapter

but if you have succeeded to build the list you can do the following

1- remove the focus from the child elements(radioButton and textviews)
  you can do this from the xml [android:focusable="false"] and for the listview [listview.setItemsCanFocus(false)]

2- make the radioButton not clickable from xml[android:clickable="false"]

3- create a variable to hold the clicked item (in the custom adapter) and make public method to update this position

4- create OnItemClickListener for the listview, update the clicked position in the adapter
and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged

5- be sure to in getView method to make the radioButton unchecked and make the view at that position is checked